# What user is running my Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, passenger

I'm trying to get a bare bones Rails app deployed under Apache, Passenger 3.0.0 and Rails 3.0.3. I'm getting all kinds of weird errors. mostly revolving around what I think is related to bundler or RAILS_ENV.

Only non-default thing about the app is that development & test environments use SQLite3 and production uses MySQL.

When hitting app from web browser Passenger is throwing errors regarding gems (sqlite3) that are specifically (in the Gemfile AND in the database.yml) declared as NOT part of the production environment.

How can I tell what user the server is trying to run my Rails app as? I would like to make sure the RAILS_ENV is set correctly for that user as I think Passenger is trying to run this app in development mode for some reason.

**Edit:** added results of `ps aux | grep httpd`

```
myserver:current elvis$ ps aux | grep httpd
elvis     4424   0.4  0.0    66152    192 s000  S+   11:03AM   0:00.00 grep httpd
_www      1950   0.0  0.2    93024   2544   ??  S    11:40PM   0:01.23 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
root      1918   0.0  1.0    93024  10244   ??  Ss   11:39PM   0:02.75 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
_www      4084   0.0  0.2    93024   2536   ??  S     9:41AM   0:00.15 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
```

and **ls -l** ...

```
myserver:current elvis$ ls -l config
total 48
-rw-rw-r--  1 aaron  admin  1923 Nov 19 21:40 application.rb
-rw-rw-r--  1 aaron  admin   326 Nov 19 21:40 boot.rb
-rw-rw-r--  1 aaron  admin   741 Nov 19 21:40 database.yml
-rw-rw-r--  1 aaron  admin  1257 Nov 19 21:40 deploy.rb
-rw-rw-r--  1 aaron  admin   149 Nov 19 21:40 environment.rb
drwxrwxr-x  5 aaron  admin   170 Nov 19 21:40 environments
drwxrwxr-x  7 aaron  admin   238 Nov 19 21:40 initializers
drwxrwxr-x  3 aaron  admin   102 Nov 19 21:40 locales
-rw-rw-r--  1 aaron  admin  1808 Nov 19 21:40 routes.rb
```

Comment: Can you show us some of the errors?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By default, passenger will run your app as the user who owns the `config/environment.rb` or `config.ru` file, see http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#user_switching

Passenger will run in the `production` environment by default unless you tell it otherwise with the `RailsEnv`, see http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#rails_env

Comment: OK. just read the user_switching link. trying to get this to work...any ideas what the owner/permission "should" be on `config/environment.rb`? same as on the website directory itself? i have a site served by apache and a symlink from w/in that main 'static' sight called 'rails' that points to my Rails app directory where the app is.

Comment: I think the user that is running the app is probably a red herring in your case.  More likely to be a rails configuration issue.  Can you run `./script/console production` from the app directory on the server?  If that throws the same error it would be easier to debug.

Comment: The owner of your config.ru/environment.rb should be whatever user you ran 'bundle install' with. 'bundle install' installs either to $HOME/.bundle or to ./help depending your Bundler settings; in case of the former, $HOME depends on the user that invoked 'bundle install'. So if you ran 'bundle install' as 'foobar' then you must also make sure your Rails app is running as 'foobar', otherwise it cannot access the gems that Bundler has installed due to permission problems.

Comment: updated my question above. the user running apache is **_www** while the owner of environment.rb is **aaron** and/or **root**. I can't log in as _www. it's a system created user. i'm not aware of it's gem locations. but users like aaron and others have different gems depending on their $PATH variables.  there is no rvm on the server.  how can i tell what gems Rails in production (assume it's _www) is pointing to?

Comment: sorry. can't edit the last comment but it should say "the users running apache are **_www** and **root** (why 2?) while the owner of environment.rb is **aaron**."

Comment: Apache's control process runs as root because it needs root to bind to port 80. After having done that it will spawn worker processes that drop their privilege to _www, for security reasons. The control process remains to be root in order to be able to spawn more worker processes.

Comment: If you ran 'bundle install' as aaron then things should work; your Rails app as launched from Phusion Passenger will try to locate the gems in aaron's home directory, as it's supposed to. Is your config.ru also owned by aaron?

Comment: This is not actually the answer, but is useful information. Is not the answer because it explain the "default" behaviour of passenger. But is not complete for "not default" behaviour. In any case: upvoted.

Answer (score 3):

You could run `ps aux | grep httpd` to see what user is running your apache process.

Comment: added results of `ps aux | grep httpd` above. among previous questions..why would there two different users running httpd processes?!?

Comment: yup. production. had a Rails 2.3.5 app running on it before. Trying to get 3.0.3 running and all hell is breaking loose.

Answer (score 0):

That's what I use to detect what user should run the rails app

```
RAILS_USER=$(stat -c '%U' /YOUR_PATH/environment.rb) 

echo "Detected rails user: $RAILS_USER"
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.