# Apache: wrong owner and permission of uploaded file

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, server, permissions

I have a website running on apache server.

Yesterday, I logged in to my server and restarted passenger, apache server.

I restarted using command:

```
touch /tmp/restart.txt
```

After that, I noticed that the new uploaded files are changed ownership to paelz (my username) and permission to -rw-------. The files were uploaded by some other users using the website.

The older files has owner apache and permission: -rw-r--r--.

As a result, the website cannot load the new uploaded files. However, it can load the older ones.

If I run chmod 644 on the new uploaded files, the website can load the files normally. However, I want a permanent solution.

I want the new uploaded file owned by apache and has permission as the old ones.

My question is what caused this issue and how can I fix it.

Comment: which was the user started the apache before you restart it form your user ?  from same user ?

Comment: No, other user started it.

Comment: Check the `umask` value of your user once, it should be `022` .. if it is `066` , then it will create file with `-rw-------` permission

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the answer. 
It is not related to apache. It is related to passenger instead.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4232091/1319283

> By default, passenger will run your app as the user who owns the
>   config/environment.rb or config.ru file, see

The config/environment.rb is owned by my account so passenger will run the app as my account.